# Cross Domain Sign In

Tags: php, html, mysql, cookies

I have a few domains all on the same server, with the same IP and the same databases - that can be accessed by all 5 of the domains.

I have recently remade my login system, so that on my main domain, the cookie works for not only the main domain but the sub domains as well.  What this means is that if a user logs into one area, they are signed in everywhere.  Which is great!  I write a cookie with their hash (taken from the DB) and check for that when loading each page, and they are automatically securely signed in.

This is lovely, but the problem then comes when switching domains, as cookies seem to be locked down to domains.  So my other domain (lets call it domain2.com) cannot read the cookie from domain1.com.

Are there any clever ways around this? I could write something to the database, such as IP, but that wouldnt be very secure as the company i work for everyone is on the same IP and therefore it wouldnt be specific.

Or I thought about maybe including a hidden iframe on the page, which actually links to a page on the main server, and pulls the information that way somehow.

I am not sure, but I am sure it can be done.  Any ideas?

Comment: I am not sure, but flash cookies may work in between domains...

Comment: another method, redirect to your domain1.com and check for cookie if present then redirect to domain2.com with cookies value

Answer (score 0):

Browsers, for good reasons, do not allow cookies to be read from any other domain.

What you can do is have domain2.com redirect to a page on domain1.com which checks if the user is logged in and if they are it redirects back to domain2.com with the user's id which can then log them in.

Answer (score -1):

You should not depending on original PHP session functions Collections. 
Here is what I have done :
    After login success , Server side should return a "session ID" to the browser and store by JavaScript or some how, mean while the "session ID" should be store in database as a successful signal and you do a login time next to the session ID if you needed.
    Now you can share the session ID in any IP server you want and make your client connect to(some trick like you redirect to the new domain and post the SID) then establish a PHP session.